# Chrome Extension Ajax Calls Returning 403

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, ssl, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Chrome Extension that takes a screenshot of the current tab and uploads it to a server via ajax on a schedule. It works perfectly on two servers I used to test it, but when I transitioned to a new server, the ajax calls are now producing 403 errors.

The only change that I can see is that the new server is has an SSL certificate, but allows plain http access. Also, I have a subdomain that I have been testing that does not have any SSL configured.

My upload script is as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), formData = new FormData(); 
xhr.addEventListener("load", processSuccess);
xhr.addEventListener("error", processError);   
formData.append("img", screenshotUrl);
formData.append("auth_string", auth_string);
formData.append("site", site);
xhr.open("POST", upload_url, true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

In my manifest, I have the following permissions:

```
"permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "tabs",
   "<all_urls>",
   "alarms",
   "storage",
   "http://**********" //the url to the script
]
```

The specific URL is overkill I assume, given the `<all_urls>` permission, and I tried it with both http and https.

I know there are complications with secure content calling or referencing insecure scripts or resources, but I didn't think having a https configured server would affect anything.

The page is browser accessible, and have the same permissions it did on the last two servers.

The console error I get is:

```
POST https://****/upload_string.php 403 (Forbidden)
(anonymous function)
target.(anonymous function)
safeCallbackApply
handleResponse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that your server *does have security requirements* that you need to meet, since it has been configured to use HTTPS on the PHP upload url. If you own the server, do research (i.e curl) and check the config files for your security setup. Inspect your HTTP request/response data in your browser's dev tools. You most likely need to use cookies and/or special headers (like Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to make POSTs to the secure server.

Comment: I figured this out about an hour ago. Namecheap was blocking my ajax calls. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HTTP status `403` means `access denied`. Does your new domain requires some authentication? If so - pass authentication information. Also check console for further information.

Comment: Agreed, there are no new authentication information requirements that I am aware of. The server script is exactly the same.